# jQuery get the data id after cloned select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In html markup I have a simple select options tag. With jQuery I am getting the data id on change the options and it is working fine. But I have also the button for clone the select options. With cloned elements by doing the alert data id on change is not working.
Here is my markup and js code

**Html Code**

```
<table>
        <tr class="resource-data">
            <td>
                <select name="product" class="product-name">
                    <option value="apple" data-id="apple">Apple</option>
                    <option value="bus" data-id="bus">Bus</option>
                    <option value="car" data-id="car">Car</option>
                    <option value="duster" data-id="duster">Duster</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right add-new-data"> Add </button>
```

**JS Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var FirstRow = jQuery("table tr.resource-data:first").clone();
        jQuery('body').on('click','.add-new-data', function() {
            var ParentRow = jQuery("table tr.resource-data").last();
            FirstRow.clone().insertAfter(ParentRow);
        });

    jQuery('select.product-name').on('change', function(e) {
        id = $(this).find("option:selected").data('id');
        alert(id);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Here is also the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/cxeza69h/) link.
So can someone tell me how to alert the cloned data id? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Side note: Using `data` **just** to get a `data-*` attribute does more work than is required, copying all `data-*` attribute values from the element to the `data` cache, etc. To **just** access a `data-*` attribute, it's best to use `attr`: `.attr("data-id")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to attach events to dynamically added elements:

```
jQuery('body').on('change','select.product-name', function(e) {
    id = $(this).find("option:selected").data('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c9h24k12/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information, you can also use `.clone(true)`, true will copy the event handlers as well.

Below is the modified/updated code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('select.product-name').on('change', function (e) {
        id = $(this).find("option:selected").data('id');
        alert(id);
    });

    var FirstRow = jQuery("table tr.resource-data:first").clone(true);
    jQuery('body').on('click', '.add-new-data', function () {
        var ParentRow = jQuery("table tr.resource-data").last();
        FirstRow.insertAfter(ParentRow);
    });

});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c9h24k12/1/)**